# Capitalize first letters of every word in array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array

```
var my_array= [ "color - black", "color - light blue", "color - Red" ]
```

And I want want to replace " - " with ":" and capitalize the first letter of every word in that array:

```
var my_array= [ "Color: Black", "Color:Light  Blue", "Color: Red" ]
```

And I try this

```
        String.prototype.capitalize = function() {
            return this.replace(/(?:^|\s)\S/g, function(a) { return a.toUpperCase(); });
        };

        for(var i=0; i < my_array.length; i++) {
            my_array[i] = my_array[i].capitalize().replace(/ -/g, ":");
        }
```

but it works only for

```
[ "Color: Black", "Color: Red" ]
```

and I get

```
 [ "Color:Light: Blue" ]
```

with two " : "

But I want to get

```
[ "Color:Light Blue" ]
```

```js
var my_array= [ "color - black", "color - light blue", "color - Red" ]

        String.prototype.capitalize = function() {
            return this.replace(/(?:^|\s)\S/g, function(a) { return a.toUpperCase(); });
        };

        for(var i=0; i < my_array.length; i++) {
            my_array[i] = my_array[i].capitalize().replace(/ -/g, ":");
        }


document.write('<pre>'+JSON.stringify(my_array));
```

Comment: Your code works fine, the problem is somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

Try this after replacing '-' to ':'

```
String.prototype.capitalize = function () {
    return this.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt){return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();});
};
```

Answer (score 1):

To capitalize use when create array or when print array

```
function capitalizeFirst(string) {
return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
}
```

To replace read

> http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp